# Saving custom form data into database

Tags: wpdb

I am a newbie to WordPress.  I've created a custom form in WordPress and I need to know where to put the WPDB PHP code to save my form data.

I tried putting it directly in my page but that didn't work.

All of the research I've looked up says not to enter it in the function file so where do I put it?

Here is the code I put in my page:

**Form Code**

```
<form id="myForm" name="myform">
    <select id="brandSel" size="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">-- Select Brand --</option>
        <option>Abba</option>
        <option>AG Hair</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    global $wpdb; 
    $inputValue = $_POST['newValue']; 
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'catalog', 
        array( 
            'brandSel' => $inputValue 
        ), 
        array( '%s' // if the field type is string ) 
    );
?>
```

Comment: Could you update your question and add your current code?

Comment: <form id="myForm" name="myform"><select id="brandSel" size="1">
<option selected="selected" value="">-- Select Brand --</option>
<option>Abba</option>
<option>AG Hair</option>
<option>Agave</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

Comment: OK, and where do you want to store that data?

Comment: In a costum table I created in my wordpress database

Comment: Could you also add to your question the code you use for saving it in that custom table?

Comment: global $wpdb;
$inputValue = $_POST['newValue'];
$wpdb->insert( 
    'catalog', 
    array( 
        'brandSel' => $inputValue
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s' // if the field type is string
    ) 
);

Answer (score 3):

OK, so here is how you should to this proper way...

In your template file you put your form:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myform" action="<?php echo esc_attr( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_my_custom_form" />
    <select id="brandSel" size="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">-- Select Brand --</option>
        <option>Abba</option>
        <option>AG Hair</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And in functions.php file (or in your plugin) you'll have to add [`admin_post_{action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)):

```
function my_save_custom_form() {
    global $wpdb;

    $inputValue = $_POST['newValue'];
    $wpdb->insert(
        'catalog',
        array( 'brandSel' => $inputValue ),
        array( '%s' ),
    );

    wp_redirect( site_url('/') ); // <-- here goes address of site that user should be redirected after submitting that form
    die;
}

add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_save_my_custom_form', 'my_save_custom_form' );
add_action( 'admin_post_save_my_custom_form', 'my_save_custom_form' );
```

Comment: I'll be using a plugin but so where do I put the "admin_post_{action}:"?

Comment: You can put it in functions.php of your theme. But if that form should be processed by a plugin, then this code should be in your plugin...

Comment: @AbelSanz Hi, did it help you?

Comment: I can't figure out where to put the function.  I'm using "Header and Footer " plugin.  Any ideas?